# Facebook cannot read open graph meta tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have been running into a really strange issue. I have two websites, they are identical in code and data, one is on a production server, the other on a testing server. On the test server, Facebook is able to read the "og:" metatags perfectly. And on the production server, on some articles that I´m trying to share it does not. Open graph debugger return 0 as a response and cannot find og:title og:description, etc.

Production server page: http://genoma.cfi.org.ar/linea/FormatoLinea?linea=1. FAILS

Tesr server page: http://test.genoma.cfi.org.ar/linea/FormatoLinea?linea=1. WORKS

Any ideas what might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: The time to first byte of that page is over 16 seconds, it's probably just timing out.

Comment: Mmm doesn´t seem to be that. Both pages take the same time to load, but it works on the test server.

Comment: @DavidG you were right. That was it. Thanks!!